# JQ Grid 4.6 not sorting by month date and year

Tags: jquery

Good morning. I'm working with `JqGrid.js` file and I notice that when I trying to sort the column containing data in this format **(mm/dd/yyyy)** it does not take the year in account. The sortType is always "text".  Any help is appreciated.

```
addLocalData = function() {
            var st = ts.p.multiSort ? [] : "", sto=[], fndsort=false, cmtypes={}, grtypes=[], grindexes=[], srcformat, sorttype, newformat;
            if(!$.isArray(ts.p.data)) {
                return;
            }
            var grpview = ts.p.grouping ? ts.p.groupingView : false, lengrp, gin;
            $.each(ts.p.colModel,function(){
                sorttype = this.sorttype || "text";
                if(sorttype === "date" || sorttype === "datetime") {
                    if(this.formatter && typeof this.formatter === 'string' && this.formatter === 'date') {
                        if(this.formatoptions && this.formatoptions.srcformat) {
                            srcformat = this.formatoptions.srcformat;
                        } else {
                            srcformat = $.jgrid.formatter.date.srcformat;
                        }
                        if(this.formatoptions && this.formatoptions.newformat) {
                            newformat = this.formatoptions.newformat;
                        } else {
                            newformat = $.jgrid.formatter.date.newformat;
                        }
                    } else {
                        srcformat = newformat = this.datefmt || "Y-m-d";
                    }
                    cmtypes[this.name] = {"stype": sorttype, "srcfmt": srcformat,"newfmt":newformat, "sfunc": this.sortfunc || null};
                } else {
                    cmtypes[this.name] = {"stype": sorttype, "srcfmt":'',"newfmt":'', "sfunc": this.sortfunc || null};
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the following modification to the code.

```
srcformat = newformat = this.datefmt || "m-d-Y";
```